# Determinar frecuencia de encendido de leds en circuito Arduino

Tags: arduino

Estoy haciendo un circuito que consta de 8 leds que se encienden y apagan en secuencia de izquierda a derecha y viceversa. El circuito funciona bien, pero éste tiene que ser controlado por un potenciómetro, o sea, que según lo vaya girando, las luces led deben encenderse a una mayor/menor velocidad.

Mi problema es, que cuando compilo, las luces se encienden y apagan correctamente, pero cuando giro el potenciómetro, independientemente de a qué lado, se ralentizan.

Adjunto el esquema y el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
int pot = A0;
int valorP;
int frecuencia;

int nPins = 8; // número de pins ocupados por los led
int pins[] = {13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6}; // pins usados

void setup()
{
  for (int i=0; i<nPins; i=i+1)
  {
    pinMode(pot, INPUT);
    pinMode(pins[i], OUTPUT);
  }  
}  

void loop() 
{
  
  //pot = analogRead(A0);
  valorP = analogRead(pot);
  frecuencia = map(valorP, 0, 1023, 200, 24);
  
  for (int i=0; i<nPins; i=i+1) // derecha
  {
    digitalWrite(pins[i], HIGH);        
    delay(frecuencia);                          
    digitalWrite(pins[i], LOW);
    delay(frecuencia);
  }
  for (int i=nPins-1; i>0; i=i-1) // izquierda
  {  
    digitalWrite(pins[i], HIGH);         
    delay(frecuencia);                          
    digitalWrite(pins[i], LOW);
    delay(frecuencia);
  }
}
```

Comment: Imprime el valor retornado por `analogRead` cuando varias el potenciometro de extremo a extremo.

Comment: Me faltó hacer eso. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

```
  valorP = analogRead(pot);
  frecuencia = map(valorP, 0, 1023, 200, 24);
```

- Con `map` se determina el rango del potenciómetro de extremo a extremo, en el paréntesis se establece un rango
- La variable `frecuencia` servirá para determinar el `delay` de los led de acuerdo a cómo se gire el potenciómetro

Esas líneas cumplen la función de acelerar o ralentizar la velocidad de la secuencia de leds